# Node js + async return results join data

Tags: jquery, node.js, postgresql

I want to bind the data of asynchronous and send through callback method ,which is defined in another function  but I am getting error of result1 not defined can anyone help me.

```
    client.query("select first_name,last_name,party_id,city,state,country from communication_detail where lower(first_name) like 'ram%'", function(err, result) {
        async.each(result.rows, function(value, done) {
            var party_id = value.party_id;

            client.query("select count(*) as goal_count from where creater_id = '"+party_id+"'", function(err, result1) {
                value.push(result1.rows[0].goal_count);
            });
            done();
        });

        callback(err, result1);

    });
```

Actual Result get:

```
[{ first_name: 'sai', last_name: 'kishore', party_id: 58, city: null, state: null, country: null},{ first_name: 'Saikishore', last_name: 'P', party_id: 50, city: null, state: null, country: 'India' }, { first_name: 'kishore', last_name: 'sai', party_id: 57, city: 'Telangana', state: 'Telangana', country: 'India,India' }]
```

Expected Result :

```
[{ first_name: 'sai', last_name: 'kishore', party_id: 58, city: null, state: null, country: null, goal_count: 10 },{ first_name: 'Saikishore', last_name: 'P', party_id: 50, city: null, state: null, country: 'India', goal_count: 0 }, { first_name: 'kishore', last_name: 'sai', party_id: 57, city: 'Telangana', state: 'Telangana', country: 'India,India', goal_count: '252' }]
```

Comment: your `callback` is outside `client.query("select * from where..", function(err` scope

Comment: Once I placed the callback inside , I am getting the error                          Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: maybe `done();` should be before `client.query("select * from where..", function(err` ?.. I don't know which db client you use

Comment: I am using postgresql, if I keep the done() before the client.query(), I am getting the same error  Can't set headers after they are sent

Comment: you use `async.each(result.rows, function(value, done) {` to operate with parent ` client.query` result, but do not consuming `result1` of child ` client.query`... maybe you should wrap it as well?..  having `value1' and `done1` as you have `result1`?..

Comment: No, Here async.each function is acting as a loop , I am getting the result from  parent client.query  passing it into  async loop  for the child client.query.I am taking the child client.query result in the result1 and passing it into the callback() method, no need of writing the value1 and done1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87360/discussion-between-vao-tsun-and-sai-kishore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In back-end code push method will not work. It may not give expected result. Try the following code. Hope it will help you.

```
client.query("select first_name,last_name,party_id,city,state,country from communication_detail where lower(first_name) like 'ram%'", function(err, result) {
async.each(result.rows, function(value, done) {
    var party_id = value.party_id;

    client.query("select count(*) as goal_count from table_name where creater_id = '" + party_id + "'", function(err, result1) {
        value.goal_count = 0;

        if (result1.rows.length > 0) {
            value.goal_count = result1.rows[0].goal_count;

        }
    });
    done();
});

callback(err, result1);});
```

Comment: This code is still invalid, because where it calls `done()` the async queries may still be executing. The same goes for the use of `callback`, which sits outside of the async, which implies that it is not really async? Looks really wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is an invalid SQL in your internal query, the `from where` part where no table name specified. But this is not the main problem. You are breaking the sequence between asynchronous queries and managing the connection session, i.e. calling `done` at the wrong time.

I can't advise you on fixing it, because for the very thing you are trying to achieve it is very awkward trying to rely on callbacks altogether.

You need to streamline the logic of running all your async queries.

The best solution I can offer, as implemented with use of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

The very example you have, with the logic you want would look as this:

```
db.query("select first_name, last_name, party_id, city,state, country from communication_detail where lower(first_name) like 'ram%'")
    .then(function (cDetails) {
        var requests = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < cDetails.length; i++) {
            var q = db.query("select count(*) as goal_count from xxx where creater_id = $1", cDetails[i].party_id);
            reguests.push(q);
        }
        return promise.all(requests);
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
            // data[k].goal_count - your counter values;
            // append them where you want;
        }
        callback(/* value, or whatever else you need to pass...*/);
    });
```

Note that I put `xxx` in place of the missing table name. Also, with this library you do not need to release the connection, it is done automatically when the sequence is finished.

And `promise.all` logic is exactly what you would get via your `async.each`.

It's just a lot cleaner that way, safer and readable. Welcome to the world of promises! ;)

By the way, the end result of what you are doing can also be achieved through just a single `JOIN` query.

Comment: There is one problem, we will get the result from the parent query and passing it to the child query using the for loop , but the loop will not iterate till the end , it will be  stopped in the middle and will return mid of the results not complete result.

Comment: Once the loop is finished, you will have the complete result: You can access `cDetails` for the complete top-level query results, and within parameter `data` you will have your complete list of counters. So the place where we use `callback` would have all the data it needs. It is up to you how you want it formatted to return, but it's all there. I don't understand why you are saying that the loop will stop in the middle - it won't; calling `promise.all` guarantees completion of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

client.query("select first_name,last_name,party_id,city,state,country from communication_detail where lower(first_name) like 'ram%'", function(err, result) {
    async.each(result.rows, function(value, callback) {
        var party_id = value.party_id;

```
    client.query("select count(*) as goal_count from where creater_id = '"+party_id+"'", function(err, result1) {
        // value.push(result1.rows[0].goal_count);
        value.goal_count = result1.rows[0].goal_count;
        callback();
    });    
}, function(err) {
  callback(err, result);
});
```

});

Comment: If I place inside the client.query, it is throwing an error of can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: 'can't set headers after they are sent' error are throw when multiple response send for one request. It might be your done() function send callback and again you are sending callback with result1 .

Comment: After removing the done() also I am facing the same problem, My query will give result of multiple columns I want to send results in a single response.

Comment: // 1st para in async.each() is the array of items
async.each(items,
  // 2nd param is the function that each item is passed to
  function(item, callback){
    // Call an asynchronous function, SELECT field from DB
    item.someAsyncCall(function (){
      // Async call is done, alert via callback
      callback();
    });
  },
  // 3rd param is the function to call when everything's done
  function(err){
    // All tasks are done now
    doSomethingOnceAllAreDone();
  }
);